# I want to generate a gray image in iOS by drawing using cgcontextfillXXX, but I failed

Tags: ios, image

```
CGRect rect = CGRectMake(0, 0, 100, 100);
float white[1] = {0.0f};
float gray[1] = {1.0f};
CGContextSetFillColorSpace(bitmap, colorSpace);
CGContextSetFillColorWithColor(bitmap, CGColorCreate(colorSpace, white));
CGContextClearRect(bitmap, rect);
CGContextSetFillColorWithColor(bitmap, CGColorCreate(colorSpace, gray));
CGContextFillEllipseInRect(bitmap, rect);
CGImageRef imgRef = CGBitmapContextCreateImage(bitmap);
UIImage *image  = [[[UIImage alloc] initWithCGImage:imgRef] autorelease];
self.imageView.image = image;
CGContextRelease(bitmap);
CGColorSpaceRelease(colorSpace);
```

the code is above.it does't work as I expect.I'm not familar to iOS CoreGraphic framework.

Answer (score 0):

See this syntax for `CGColorCreate` in [apple Document](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/graphicsimaging/Reference/CGColor/Reference/reference.html)

Example code is :

```
CGFloat components[]={r, g, b, 1.f};
drawColor=CGColorCreate(colorSpace, components);
CGColorSpaceRelease(colorSpace);
```

**Note :** You have to define `r,g,b` as your wish which are all `CGFloat` type..